# The USB port only recognizes a WD Elements hard drive

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3

On my laptop I have a USB port that only works with a WD hard drive, I tried to connect another device such as a mouse, keyboard, USB memory and nothing, the strange thing is that in the device manager the port does not appear either, as if it did not exist.

This started to fail from the first time I connect that hard drive to my laptop, and also connect it to another pc as a test and nothing strange happens, the port continues to work well.

My laptop is an Asus Tuf F15 with windows 11

Comment: This sounds like a driver issue. Have you tried other external hard drives?

Answer (score 0):

If the WD Elements drive is the larger desktop-type model (with an external power source), it's possible that the data part of the port is working but not the power. Do you have another externally-powered device to plug in and try this? In any case, it sounds like the port is at least partially bad.
If it was a case of a missing USB driver, no USB device would work. Since one does, albeit just one, maybe this is the cause.

Comment: No, the disk is portable, so the power part works well, also if I connect a cell phone it starts to charge